# how to revert the complete source code in github repository

Tags: git, github

We have two branching in GitHub, master and development - master always contains production code. Since we are moving code from master branch to production - if any failure occur in production we would like to revert the complete code with previous version of source code in GitHub master branch. How can we do this in GitHub? Is there any command available to do this.

We want to complete rollback of previous version of master branch code

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to revert a commit in the `master` branch is to just use `git revert`:

```
git checkout master
git revert <SHA-1>
```

Here replace `<SHA-1>` with the hash of the commit you want to revert.  Also likely would be the case where you want to revert a range of commits in `master`.  You can also use `git revert` with a commit range, e.g.

```
git revert A^..D
```

This command would revert commits `A` through `D` *inclusive* on both ends.

You *could* also nuke the commit you want to go away by doing `git reset --hard HEAD~3` or something similar to this.  However, since `master` is public and almost certainly shared by others, rewriting the history in this way could be dangerous.

Comment: No - I don't want to revert the code in development branch. I want to revert the code in master branch

Comment: Tim's answer refer to master branch